# Sending messages to websocket server with flash

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, glassfish, websocket

Basically i am trying to create a websocket based live chat for a few websites i work on.

the server i have up and working no bother running on the javax.websocket package on a glassfish server.

the standard HTML5 websocket interface i also have working no bother.

the problem is that about 10-20% or our users dont use an HTML5 compatible browser so i need a fallback. Do far the best option i can find seems to be running a swf as a middle man between the websocket server and HTML. The problem there being that action script doesnt support websockets as standard so im having to write my own wrapper.

So far i can connect to the server and perform a successful handshake, i can also receive messages from the server with no issues, the problem is sending messages.

I have had a look through https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2 at the theory of the data frame for a websocket package and written an attempt at this, i have also looked through various other open source library's without any luck. What happens is whenever i send a message to the server i get a response of
RSV bit(s) incorrectly set.
and then the connection closes (as it should with the websocket protocol).

A large part of the problem i suspect is that this is the first time i have ever even looked at action script never mind attempted using it.

i was just wondering if anyone else had been having this problem/response and preferably has found a solution

in an idea world im looking for a tutorial that i could use to actually understand the creation of the frame better but i cant seem to find one :P

thanks
Matt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As it turns out it was just one of those bizarre bugs that happened for basically no reaseon, i ended up re-writing the section of code that manages the creation of websocket frames and frame fragmentation and it just worked.

ive had a few programmers look the the two examples of code including an action script developer and none of them can work out why the one snippet works and the other doesnt.

On the upside going back over the process has given me a better understanding of the protocol. If there is anyone else that has been having a similar problem feel free to get in touch and i will see if i can help you out.